# overlaying and cleaning up mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

Im not sure if i am asking the right question but here it goes. The project I am working on consist of several 3D scans of a model that I then composite together. When I do this i have several areas where the mesh over lay and and create bad textures, along with other things.

My question is, is there a simple way of removing this mesh and simplifying the model.
Currently i go in and select vertices and delete each one individual. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.[image][image][image]

Comment: Hello :). I think the new remesher in Blender 2.82 could help here.

Comment: A helpful search-term would be 'retopology' ... unless you have reasons, it would be a lot easier to model this from scratch ..:)